# How to create a monad using StateT, ContT, and ReaderT?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, continuations

How do I create a monad which uses State, Cont, and Reader transformers? I would like to read an environment, and update/use state. However, I would also like to pause/interrupt the action. For example, if a condition is met, the state remains unchanged.

So far I have a monad using ReaderT and StateT, but I cannot work out how to include ContT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Test where
-- monads
import   Data.Functor.Identity (Identity, runIdentity)
import   Control.Monad.State
import   Control.Monad.Reader
import   Control.Monad.Cont

-- reader environment
type In = Integer

-- cont: if true then pause, else continue 
type Pause = Bool

-- state environment:
newtype StateType = StateType { s :: Integer }

newtype M r = M {_unM :: ReaderT In (ContT Pause (StateT StateType Identity)) r}
  deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
           , MonadReader In
           , MonadCont   Pause
           , MonadState  StateType
           )

-- run monadic action
runM :: In -> Pause -> StateType -> M r -> StateType
runM inp pause initial act
  = runIdentity             -- unwrap identity
  $ flip execStateT initial -- unwrap state
  $ flip runContT   pause   -- unwrap cont
  $ flip runReaderT inp     -- unwrap reader
  $ _unM act                -- unwrap action
```

This gives the error:

```
* Expected kind `* -> *', but `Pause' has kind `*'
* In the first argument of `MonadCont', namely `Pause'
  In the newtype declaration for `M'
  |
24|         , MonadCont  Pause
  |
```

Ok, but why does `Pause` need kind `* -> *`?... I'm drowning in types, in need of explanation. What form does `Pause` have to take, a function? How does ContT integrate? Ultimately, I plan to use Cont for a control structure.

Comment: A few random comments: the order in which you "stack" the monad transformers sometimes (often) matters. I can't see if you got it right or not. Anyway, `ContT Pause` is `ContT Bool` and it looks a bit weird since it's `(a -> m Bool) -> m Bool`, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: @chi In terms of stack ordering, I want to "read" an Integer, if the integer is odd then no state update occurs, if even then add it to the state (an accumulator). That is why I stacked them how they are, `ReaderT (ContT (StateT)))`. May be incorrect, been reading docs to confirm. Concerning `ContT Bool`, I think this is the stem of my confusion. I originally looked at it like `ReaderT` or `StateT` which use `In` and `StateType` respectively. What is `(a -> m Bool) -> m Bool`?  Seems more abstract than `StateType` or the Reader environment type. How does the `ContT` use the function in `runM`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike `MonadReader` and `MonadState`, the `MonadCont` type class [takes only one parameter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#t:MonadCont).  Since that parameter `m` must be a `Monad`, it must have kind `* -> *`.

In your deriving clause, you want `MonadCont,` not `MonadCont Pause`.

added in response to followup question:

`ContT` [is defined as:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Cont.html#ContT)

```
newtype ContT r m a = ContT { runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r }
```

Note that the `r` in your definition of `newtype M r` is passed as the final (`a`) parameter to `ContT`.  Plugging in the variables, you have

```
ContT Bool (State StateType) a = ContT { 
    runContT :: (a -> State StateType Bool) -> (State StateType Bool)
  }
```

This provides a computational context in which you can manipulate the `StateType`, and use delimited continuations.  Eventually, you will construct a `ContT Bool (State StateType) Bool`.  Then you can run the continuation (with [`evalContT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:evalContT)), and return to the simpler `State StateType` context.  (In practice, you may unwrap all 3 of your monad transformers in the same part of your program.)

Comment: Much thanks! Could you explain what the parameters to `ContT` mean? Namely in the line `M r = {... Reader In (ContT (???) (StateT StateType Identity)) r }`.

Comment: ContT [is defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Cont.html#ContT) as `newtype ContT r m a = ContT { runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r }`.  `m` is the underlying Monad - `(StateT StateType Identity)`) in your example.  `a` is the value at the current stage of computation.  These `m` and `a` are the same for every Monad Transformer.  `r` is the type at which `ContT` will eventually be run / eliminated, with `evalContT`